# Determine xinput device manufacturer and model?

Tags: xorg, xinput

I'm trying to find the device manufacturer and model of my keyboard and touch pad so I can write an XOrg configuration file targeting it via:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchProduct "Product Name"
    MatchVendor "Vendor Name"
EndSection
```

How can I discover a device's product and vendor name using a CLI tool? I'd like to nail down my Bluetooth touchpad and keyboard so as to be able to tailor Xorg configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For USB devices on Linux, you can use:

```
lsusb -v | grep -e idProduct -e idVendor
```

For the IDs only:

```
grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/id*
```

`lsusb` uses `/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids` to translate *ids* to *names*, I don't know whether Xorg would use the same source.

Comment: Awesome, I can now see my USB devices, but I actually need to find Bluetooth info. This information is exactly what I'm looking for, just need it for my Bluetooth devices. I can find the hex vendor ids on Bluetooth devices, but I can't seem to find actual vendor or product names.

Comment: -1 because this doesn’t work for non-usb devices. And it even doesn’t work for all usb devices, because `lsusb` often does not show a product name. ManuelSchneid3r’s answer worked best for me, that is: `xinput list`.

Comment: This answer is now outdated: `lsusb` (from `usbutils`) [since this commit](https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/commit/c6282a7a) no longer uses `usb.ids` directly, but `udev` `hwid` ([intro](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2019/02/adding-entries-to-udev-hwdb.html) which is part of systemd. That one has a [vendored `usb.ids`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5efbd0bf/hwdb.d/usb.ids) that appears to be regularly imported from the offical [`usb.ids`](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) and generates `hwdb` entries [in this code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5efbd0bf/hwdb.d/ids_parser.py).

Answer (score 28):

### Device Product Name (Model)

Get the xinput device Product Name (or *model*) using `xinput list`. Example output might look something like this:

```
# xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless        id=16 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3  [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12 [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

In the above output, the model or product name for the Touchscreen device is "ELAN Touchscreen".

### Device Path (Node)

To get the xinput device Vendor Name (or *manufacturer*), we need to know the device Path (also called Device Node) to query, and then ask `udevadm info`. You can get the path by listing the xinput properties for a device and finding the 'Device Node' value.

From our previous example the Device Node value for the Touchscreen, which says it has `id=10`, could be found like this:

```
# xinput list-props 10 | grep 'Device Node'
    Device Node (253):    "/dev/input/event9"
```

### Device Vendor Name (Manufacturer)

Now we can get the xinput device Vendor Name (or *manufacturer*) by looking at the value for the `VENDOR` property returned by `udevadm info` for the device with our path name found above:

```
# udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/input/event9 | grep 'VENDOR='
ID_VENDOR=ELAN
```

In the output above, the manufacturer or vendor name for the Touchscreen would be "ELAN".

### XOrg Configuration

Putting it all together, we can create a new [XOrg configuration `InputClass` Section](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading9) to match specific device vendors, products or paths. Using our previous examples, this section matches any Touchscreen Product manufactured by the ELAN Vendor:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "elan touchscreen catchall"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchProduct "Touchscreen"
    MatchVendor "ELAN"
EndSection
```

Thanks to [@Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas), [@Daniel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/16287/daniel-k) and [@ManuelSchneid3r](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27330/manuelschneid3r)

Comment: `xinput list` shows both vendor and product name in one line, separated only by a space char. In my case it was *TrulyErgonomic.com Truly Ergonomic Computer Keyboard* instead of *Truly Ergonomic Computer Keyboard*. But `MatchProduct` seems to work with both strings: vendor and product name (as listed by `xinput list`) or only product name (as listed by `udevadm`).

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.

Comment: And while `xinput list` allows spaces and `/`, in `udevadm` output they are replaced with underscore. So in `xinput list` I see `GN Netcom A/S Jabra EVOLVE LINK MS`, but in udevadm I see  `ID_VENDOR=GN_Netcom_A_S`

Comment: [`udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/input/event9`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udev#List_the_attributes_of_a_device)

Answer (score 2):

`MatchProduct "Product Name"` does not work with the output of Stephane's suggestion `lsusb -v | grep -e idProduct -e idVendor`. I just tested it.

`xinput list` outputs the correct string that works with `MatchProduct`

Comment: Does `xinput list` list both vendor and product together? Do you know how to work out which is which?

Comment: @Sparhawk `xinput list` shows the Product name but not the Vendor name. `udevadm info` shows the Vendor name but not the Product name.

Comment: @Christopher I can't actually remember why I wanted this information, but thanks for replying, and hopefully it can help someone else.

Comment: @Christopher: No, `xinput list` show both vendor and product name in one line, separated by a space. I needed to use @DanielK’s answer to find only the product name. But `udevadm` shows ***_*** instead of spaces. Easier to use might be the *MatchUSBID* found with `lsusb` or `lsusb -v`.

Comment: Ok, I just tested it: It works both with the whole string from `xinput list`, which is vendor and product name (at least in my case), and with the product name only (which I got from `udevadm` replacing the **_** chars with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the following commands to be useful in finding the model/vendor for use with the xorg.conf configuration.

From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=753773: (where /dev/sdx is replaced with the target device's device path i.e. /dev/input/mouse1)

```
udevadm info --query=all --path=$(udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/sdx)
```

According to http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Input_device_configuration:

```
udevadm info --export-db | grep ID_MODEL
```

Comment: But this lists the product names with ***_*** instead of spaces. In my case it was *Truly_Ergonomic_Computer_Keyboard* instead of *Truly Ergonomic Computer Keyboard*. `xinput list` shows it correctly, but vendor and product name together in one line.