# How to set xinput properties triggered by udev device connection?

Tags: udev, usb-device, xinput

I'm trying to set `xinput` properties for a USB input device whenever it is connected. I have seen [solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340329/4292) that require a script to run in the background and poll USB devices, but I would like to find a triggered approach rather than one involving user-space polling.

I have tried creating a `udev` rule that runs a script on device connection, but it appears that the connected device is not yet visible to `xinput` when the `udev` `add` rule is triggered. This appears to be a constant order of events rather than a race condition as adding a `sleep` command to the script also delays the device being listed in `xinput list`.

Is there any reliable method of setting `xinput` properties for devices when they are connected?

Comment: why trigger them on udev and not on xinput events? the former requires root, it's tricky, system-dependent, and messes with stuff it has not business messing with. The latter could be done be any x11 client, via the xinput or xinput2 extension. Also have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523959/308316).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My solution was to trigger the udev rule with `ACTION=="bind"` instead of `ACTION=="add"` (Because I saw with `udevadm monitor` that it was last action when I connected a mouse)

Answer (score 2):

The normal method is to write an `xorg.conf` file, use the `InputClass` matching methods, and set properties directly in `xorg.conf`. No script, no race condition, no explicit meddling with `udev`; it just works, though it doesn't use `xinput` directly...

See `man xorg.conf` for details.

Comment: `xinput` has properties listing, but `xorg.conf` does not. Is there a way to know the property exact name to be used in `xorg.conf`?

Comment: Ok, never mind, found it `man(4) libinput` , have nice time.

Comment: +1 for the clue, but for exactly how-to you must look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58117/determine-xinput-device-manufacturer-and-model#answer-220082