# Notifications about X input device changes

Tags: x11, cinnamon, d-bus, xinput

I am developing an applet for Cinnamon which lets me enable/disable the touchscreen of my laptop. This also shows the current status of the touchscreen.

Currently I am using synchronous calls to the `xinput` command to query or set the current state of the touchscreen device.

This however has at least two problems:

- Calling shell commands earns my applet a warning upon installation
- The applet is not notified if other actors change the status of the touchscreen device

Therefore I am looking for a way to automatically (e.g. pubsub subscription or DBus) receive notification about status changes of my touchscreen X device.

Extra nice would be a way to enable/disable the device through this other channel as well, so my applet is no longer marked as dangerous.

Comment: look at my answer and examples [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523959/308316). Your applet could listen itself to XInput events, which go through the common X11 connection.

Comment: Seems promising, I'll have a look at it later.