Permanently set layout for all keyboards in X11
On my laptop running Gentoo Linux with StumpWM as a window manager, I have a custom keyboard layout called daselt, which I'm using all the time. Until now I've set it by automatically running setxkbmap daselt daselt at startup, but the trouble is that this only sets it for keyboards that are always connected (such as my laptop keyboard), but not external keyboards that have to be re-added after suspend, for instance. What I'd like to do is set the keyboard layout as a default that all keyboards are set to when they are connected. So I ran
sudo localectl set-x11-keymap daselt "" daselt

and it produced the file 00-keyboard.conf, whose contents are
# Written by systemd-localed(8), read by systemd-localed and Xorg. It's
# probably wise not to edit this file manually. Use localectl(1) to
# update this file.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "daselt"
        Option "XkbVariant" "daselt"
EndSection

Yet, when I, for instance, suspend my laptop, then wake it up again, my external keyboard, it is added with the normal en-us layout. How can I make it so the daselt layout is automatically applied to all added keyboards?

Could it be as simple as using the Settings tool of whatever desktop environment you use and setting the layout there? I don't remember ever seeing this problem (layout changing on suspend) on any system I've used. You mention X11, so I assume you do have some desktop environment running, right? Or is this pure X?

@terdon I'm running StumpWM as a window manager. Stump has a plugin for switching keyboard layouts, but I think it's mostly just a simple interface to setxkbmap and I remember having had problems with getting it to work. I'll look it up though and see if it does anything more than that.

@terdon Yeah, as I thought, the plugin is basically just a wrapper around setxkbmap.

I suspect you might have more luck if you can figure out why the setting is lost in the first place. I mean, otherwise, sure you could even hack something horrible like an infinite loop running the setxkbmap every second (bleh) but if we can understand why the setting is getting lost in the first place, that is probably the best solution.

@terdon I don't think the setting is getting lost. The internal keyboard of my laptop remains configured to that layout even after I suspend and restart the laptop. I think the keymap does not remain for an external keyboard because the system re-scans peripherals upon wake-up and applies the standard keymap to any keyboards it finds, which apparently it still sees as the en-us map. At least that's what I think is going on.

Ah, I see. Crap, then we will probably need to tweak udev...

I've never used StumpWM, but from the description my first thought was to write a udev hook which would call setxkbmap. Of course, DISPLAY will need to be set.

@terdon With XKB, newly plugged-in keyboards get a default configuration, rather than whatever configuration has already applied. An external keyboard counts as newly plugged in on resume from suspend because the corresponding communication bus is reset; an internal keyboard might remain logically connected during suspend. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523635/prevent-keyboard-layout-reset-when-usb-keyboard-is-plugged-in for a similar question, but not duplicate because I would have thought that Alexander's system-level configuration would work.

It seems the problem was that I ran
localectl set-x11-keymap daselt "" daselt

as root. I ran the same command as my normal user and it seems to have worked.
