# Problem with udev rules

Tags: bash, udev

I'm having difficulties running a .sh script when I plug in a Bluetooth keyboard.

I'm using the following udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", RUN+="./scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh"
```

The script doesn't appear to be activated when I connect my keyboard. I have also tried "./scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh", "/bin/bash /scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh", and "sh /scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh". I don't understand why this script is not activated.

If I instead use the following udev rule

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/joe/tempfolder"
```

Then the folder /home/joe/tempfolder is created when I connect the keyboard.

I have saved the rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-addicleverkeybindings.sh. The permissions etc. are: 
-rw-r--r-- 1 joe  root    80 Aug 11 19:53 50-addicleverkeyboard.rules.

The script that I'm trying to run is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1
cheese

remote_id=$(
    xinput list |
    sed -n 's/.*iClever IC-BK06 Keyboard  .*id=\([0-9]*\).*keyboard.*/\1/p'
)
[ "$remote_id" ] || exit

xkbcomp -i $remote_id /scripts/icleverlayout.xkb $DISPLAY
```

And  ls -la gives  -rwxr-xr-x  1 joe  root   222 Aug 11 20:00 icleverkeybindings.sh.

If I call simply /scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh from the terminal this works fine.

The script changes the key bindings for my keyboard, I added in the pause in case somehow the script was getting called before xinput knew the keyboard was there, and I added in cheese just to make sure that I knew if it was definitely getting called or not.

Can anyone advise me on how to change my rule so that the script is called?

Thank you

EDIT:
To clarify, I created a folder /scripts/, so /scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh is the absolute filepath

Comment: what is the full path of `./scripts` directory? .... do you have a `/scripts` directory in your filesystem?

Comment: 1. You have use a full path to `./scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh`. 2. Make sure it has executable bit set.

Comment: /scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh is the full path. does 'make sure the executable bit is set' mean 'run chmod +x ' on the script? because I did that

Comment: I've converted my previous comment to answer.

Comment: @Joe: yes, it means that

Comment: It is better to set that configuration within xorg (i dont know much xkbcomp), udev is an alien to the source and target. Like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439528/12209

Answer (score 1):

As it says in `man udev`:

```
   RUN{type}
       Add a program to the list of programs to be executed after
       processing all the rules for a specific event, depending on
       "type":

       "program"
           Execute an external program specified as the assigned
           value. If no absolute path is given, the program is
           expected to live in /lib/udev; otherwise, the absolute
           path must be specified.
```

You can also check what `udev` logs:

```
Aug 11 21:57:43 ja-VirtualBox systemd-udevd[2998]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/./scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh' './scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh': No such file or directory
```

Or non-systemd systems:

```
[769712.027218] udevd[13015]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/./scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh' './scripts/icleverkeybindings.sh': No such file or directory
```

That being said, you have to either pass an absolute path to
`icleverkeybindings.sh` in your udev rule, something like this:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", RUN+="/path/to/icleverkeybindings.sh"
```

or put `icleverkeybindings.sh` in `/lib/udev` and just use a filename in udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", RUN+="icleverkeybindings.sh"
```

In both cases you need to make sure that `icleverkeybindings.sh`
has an executable bit is set because otherwise:

```
Aug 11 22:07:49 ja-VirtualBox systemd-udevd[3345]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/icleverkeybindings.sh' 'icleverkeybindings.sh': Permission denied
Aug 11 22:07:49 ja-VirtualBox systemd-udevd[3325]: Process 'icleverkeybindings.sh' failed with exit code 2.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did set the executable bit for the script, and I did put the absolute path. How did you check the udev log?

Comment: It depends on your system configuration, it might be in `/var/log/syslog` or in `dmesg`.