# xorg: assign touch screens to monitors - with serial number

Tags: xorg, udev, multi-monitor, touch-screen

I'm using an application with two identical (ELO branded) touch screens on xorg. I would like to automatically assign the correct touch panel to the corresponding monitor, even if usb cables or monitor cables got re-plugged. (I would have to run a setup utility once, to check which panel belongs to which monitor, but that's not the problem).

Both monitors and touch panels have serial numbers and preferrably, I'd put these in a configuration file, look them up at startup and run the correct xinput commands from there. Preferrably this should be done through udev, as that is probably the correct way.

What I did before is:

- run `xinput` to see the inputs:

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard    ... etcetera
```

Then list the devices for the Atmel panels:
`xinput --list-props 10|grep Device.Node|cut -f2 -d'"'`, which gives me `/dev/input/event11` (do this for the other 3 Atmel ids as well).
Then run udevadm to see which of these are touch panels *and* read the serial ID:
`udevadm info /dev/input/event11`
gives me

```
N: input/event11
L: 0
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7:1.1-event
S: input/by-id/usb-Atmel_Atmel_maXTouch_Digitizer_E21R077282-event-if01
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1/0003:03EB:8A6E.0003/input/input12/event11
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event11
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=75
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5462678
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=1
E: ID_INPUT_WIDTH_MM=341
E: ID_INPUT_HEIGHT_MM=273
E: ID_VENDOR=Atmel
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Atmel
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=03eb
E: ID_MODEL=Atmel_maXTouch_Digitizer
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Atmel\x20maXTouch\x20Digitizer
E: ID_MODEL_ID=8a6e
E: ID_REVISION=1034
E: ID_SERIAL=Atmel_Atmel_maXTouch_Digitizer_E21R077282
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=E21R077282
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7:1.1
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_7_1_1
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/3eb/8a6e:usb-0000:00:14.0-7
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7:1.1-event /dev/input/by-id/usb-Atmel_Atmel_maXTouch_Digitizer_E21R077282-event-if01
```

So now I have the serial ID for the panel.

Then I need the displays that are connected: `xrandr -q --verbose` shows monitors and the edid-block. Because the edid information is read only and immutable, I can use that as a fixed identifier for now. (No need to run `edid-decode` although I could).

I'm leaving out the scripting that fetches the monitor names from the xrandr output; but finally, I can connect the Atmel Digitizer that has `ID_SERIAL_SHORT=E21R077282` to monitor DP-4, with `xinput --map-to-output 10 DP-4`; and add the other Atmel panel to DP-6.

But this feels like a whole lot of number crunching, to go from `id=10` to `/dev/input/event11` to the serial number.

- Can this be done with udev rules?
- Should I make a udev rule that distinguishes  on `ID_SERIAL_SHORT`?
- But then, what should it do with that information?
- I.e. how can I transfer the information from udev to xorg?
- And is `udev` able to fetch the monitor information from xorg as well? Or how should I build the connection between the two?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you cannot (update: you *can*, see below)

`udev` is all about USB-device-handling. At the time of plugging something into a USB port, a `udev` ACTION takes place and you can associate a number of things, including the running of any custom script in a udev rule.

However, there is (a) no guarantee an X11 server is running at that time, and (b) even if it is running, it may be owned by a different user, and it would be a security breach if you could sneak something into the X11 server through a privileged script invoked by the `udev` system.

For example, you cannot legitimately invoke an `xinput` command as a part of the udev rule, it should not be able to do anything, even though the very same command would run just fine if invoked by a user who is logged in on the desktop.

There are lots of suggestions out there for rules like (example is for a Wacom touch tablet):

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ACTION=="add", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/someusername/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/wacom.sh $env{DEVNAME}"
```

where the `wacom.sh` script in turn make appropriate `xinput` calls, but they assume a number of things which are not necessarily true: that DISPLAY is, in fact, `:0.0`, or that root has access to the specified `.Xauthority` file (not always true, depends on how the home directory is mounted) or that the username is always the same on a multi-user system.

The only legitimate way out is to run a script by the user, manually, after plugging in the USB touch device.  You can associate it with a button on the panel/desktop, but it cannot be invoked by the `udev` system.

Here's an example I use to map two identical touchscreen monitors arranged side-by-side into one extended desktop.  I use xinput/udevadm (there are different detection schemes depending on the device) and hard-coded serial numbers of all screens and devices to map the left stylus/touch screen onto the left monitor, and the right ones onto the right monitor.  The exact search strings in parsing out EDID depend very much on the OS and edid-decode versions, so may need adjusting to your situation, I could not figure out a universal way of extracting EDID information.

```
#!/bin/bash

LEFT_USB=XXXXXXX
LEFT_HDMI=YYYYYYY
RIGHT_USB=ZZZZZZZ
RIGHT_HDMI=TTTTTTT

### all xinput devices
ids=`xinput list --id-only`

left_ids=""
right_ids=""

for i in $ids
do
  node=`xinput list-props $i | grep Device\ Node | cut -f2 -d\"`
  if [ ! -z "$node" ]; then
    serial=`udevadm info $node | grep ID_SERIAL_SHORT | cut -f2 -d=`
    touch_id=`xinput list $i | grep "TouchClass" | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'`
    pen_id=`xinput list $i | grep Pen | cut -f2 -d= | cut -f1`
    if [ "$serial" == "$LEFT_USB" ]; then 
      left_ids+="$pen_id $touch_id "
    elif [ "$serial" == "$RIGHT_USB" ]; then 
      right_ids+="$pen_id $touch_id "
    fi
  fi
done

left_ids=`echo $left_ids | uniq | xargs`
right_ids=`echo $right_ids | uniq | xargs`

### all connected displays
DISPLAYS=`xrandr | grep \ connected | cut -f1 -d\  `
for d in $DISPLAYS
do
  serial=`xrandr -q --verbose | sed -n  "/$d connected/,/HDCP/p" | edid-decode | grep '\ \ Serial\ Number:' | cut -f2 -d: | xargs`
  if   [ "$serial" == "$LEFT_HDMI" ]; then
    for i in $left_ids
    do
      xinput map-to-output $i $d
    done
  elif [ "$serial" == "$RIGHT_HDMI" ]; then
    for i in $right_ids
    do
      xinput map-to-output $i $d
    done
  fi
done

exit 0
```

*Edit:*

An interesting alternative is proposed
by imdn [in the Arch Linux System Administration Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1626055#p1626055). 
The basic idea is to make use of a semaphore file which gets created
by the `udev` rule, and add an `inotifywait` to the X configuration
(start a `file-inotify` service from `~/.xprofile`, for example)
to monitor any changes to that lock file,
and executing an appropriate `xinput` command when that happens. 
Seems workable in principle, but I could not get it going.

The only proper solution is to change the X configuration itself, and invoke setting of appropriate options upon configuration of a new pointer device.  If the device name is unique, adding a rule in `/etc/X11/xorg.d/*` based on `MatchProduct` is all that is needed. This example is for a Wacom Cintiq tablet, tested on Ubuntu 23.04, xfce4:

```
## this file is /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf
# xrandr: 
#   DVI-0 connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (main monitor)
#   DisplayPort-0 connected 1920x1080+2560+0 (Wacom Cintiq tablet)
# Wacom tablet can be configured to be --right-of 1920x1080+2560+0 or --below 1920x1080+0+1600
#   --right-of means x-shift=2560/(2560+1920)=0.571429, x-scale=1920/(2560+1920)=0.428571, yscale=1080/1600=0.675
#    Option "TransformationMatrix" "0.428571 0 0.571429 0 0.675 0 0 0 1"
#   --below means    y-shift=1600/(1600+1080)=0.597015, y-scale=1080/(1600+1080)=0.402985, xscale=1920/2560=0.75
#    Option "TransformationMatrix" "0.75 0 0 0 0.402985 0.597015 0 0 1"
# Refs:
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58117/determine-xinput-device-manufacturer-and-model
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/178140/xinput-coordinate-transformation-matrix-in-xorg-conf
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations
#
# Can match by a common substring for all Wacom devices (as reported by xinput):
#    MatchProduct "Wacom ISDv5 307 Pen stylus"
#    MatchProduct "Wacom ISDv5 307 Pen eraser"
#    MatchProduct "Wacom ISDv5 309 Finger touch"

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom Cintiq"
    Driver "wacom"
    MatchProduct "Wacom ISDv5"
    Option "TransformationMatrix" "0.428571 0 0.571429 0 0.675 0 0 0 1"
EndSection
```

Things get more complicated if there are two identical devices that have the same product ids, the only unique identifier being the serial number.  Unfortunately, `MatchSerial` options does not exist in xorg, but one can set a `TAG` in `udev` rules, and then use `MatchTag` in `xorg`.

*Edit:*

Finally, this is the **proper solution**.  The following example is for my two FlatFrog panels side-by-side.  The beauty of this particular solution is that all the subdevices inherit these scaling properties when they get activated, so no need to chase touch/stylus/eraser separately.

```
### this is /etc/udev/rules.d/69-flatfrog.rules
ACTION=="remove", GOTO="flatfrog_end"
KERNEL!="event[0-9]*", GOTO="flatfrog_end"

ATTRS{idVendor}=="25b5", ATTRS{idProduct}="0082", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="XXXXXXXXX", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="FlatFrogRHS"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="25b5", ATTRS{idProduct}="0082", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="YYYYYYYYY", ENV{ID_INPUT.tags}="FlatFrogLHS"

LABEL="flatfrog_end"
```

```
### this is /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-flatfrog.conf
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "RHstylus"
    MatchTag   "FlatFrogRHS"
    Option    "TransformationMatrix" "0.5 0 0.5 0 1 0 0 0 1"
EndSection
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "LHstylus"
    MatchTag   "FlatFrogLHS"
    Option     "TransformationMatrix" "0.5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1"
EndSection
```

Ref: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1592